# How can I get all network requests and full response data when loading a page by Puppeteer-sharp?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I`m trying to get all network requests (as in the chrome dev tools network tab) by Puppeteer-sharp, like it works with JS Puppeteer:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('response', async (response) => {}
```

I cant find the solution in documentation of Puppeteer-sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Response](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_Response) event:

```
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
page.Response += (sender, e) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Response.Url);
}
```